# C# WPF: How do I call a method with data binding when a window is closing?

Tags: c#, wpf, caliburn.micro

I've used CaliburnMicro to implement data binding for my data grid:

```
<Window x:Class="TicketDemo.Views.ShellView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TicketDemo.Views"
        mc:Ignorable="d" FontSize="20"
        Title="ShellView" Height="450" Width="800"
        Closing="{Binding Path=OnClose}">
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid x:Name="Tickets" AlternatingRowBackground="LightGray" CanUserAddRows="True"
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                  >
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Title" Binding="{Binding Path=Title}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Content" Binding="{Binding Path=Content}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I tried to use the same data binding to link a method called OnClose() to the Closing event.

```
using Caliburn.Micro;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using TicketDemo.Models;

namespace TicketDemo.ViewModels
{
    class ShellViewModel : Screen
    {
        public BindableCollection<TicketModel> Tickets { get; set; }

        public ShellViewModel()
        {
            Tickets = SQLiteDataAccess.LoadTickets();
        }

        public void OnClose(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Window Closing");
        }
    }
}
```

When I debug the program, I get this message:

```
using Caliburn.Micro;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace TicketDemo.Views
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for ShellView.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class ShellView : Window
    {
        public ShellView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            MessageBox.Show("Hello");
        }
    }
}
```

> System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: ''Provide value on
>   'System.Windows.Data.Binding' threw an exception.' Line number '9' and
>   line position '9'.'
>
> InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type
>   'System.Reflection.RuntimeEventInfo' to type
>   'System.Reflection.MethodInfo'.

[The SO post answering a question about this exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24677421/command-binding-unable-to-cast-object-of-type-system-reflection-runtimeeventinf/24678321) relates to buttons, but this is an event, so I don't think it's helpful to resolve my problem.

Comment: Please post code as text, not as image.

Comment: you should replace Closing="{Binding Path=OnClose}" with this Closing="OnClose"

Comment: @FerasSalim This will not work as OnClose is in the ViewMode, not the View

Comment: You can bind only to properties, not to methods

Comment: if you use view model, you should bind to properties not methods, you can create relay commands and bind it

Comment: Great thanks, could you post a solution showing how to use a relay command?

Comment: @PianoTelope how do you bind view model to view?

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/a/10737161/2374987

Comment: I'm using CaliburnMicro to set up the ViewModel. The code in that answer doesn't answer my question. Please could you write an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using caliburn, the event is declared like this:

replace `Closing="{Binding Path=OnClose}"`

by

`cal:Message.Attach="[Event Closing] = [Action OnClose]"`

(dont forget to add `xmlns:cal="http://www.caliburnproject.org"`)

in ViewModel you write:

```
    public void OnClose()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Window Closing");
    }
```